# Adding a third left join drops initial table out of scope

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, join, left-join

If I do a LINQ query with 2 left joins, I'm fine, but once I add a third left join my initial table in my "from" is no longer available to the 3rd left join and I get an error:

```
Source compile error, line ##: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
```

For example:

```
from x in [TableX]
join a in [TableA]
    on x.ItemNumber equals a.ItemNumber into aLeftJoin 
from aLeft in aLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join b in [TableB]
    on x.ItemNumber equals b.ItemNumber into bLeftJoin 
from bLeft in bLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in [TableC]
    on x.ItemNumber equals c.ItemNumber into cLeftJoin 
from cLeft in cLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
 x.ItemNumber, 
 ...
}
```

Then I get the error on line `on x.ItemNumber equals c.ItemNumber into cLeftJoin` and it doesn't matter if I reorder the left joins, it still errors on the third one.

Comment: Use `into` after each join and refer to them in next join.

Comment: I don't follow... wouldn't that negate the left join by referring to something in a previous left join?  I need these to be independent left joins.

Comment: Try and expect result.

Comment: since you specify linq-to-sql, i might be old school but when i have this kind of query to do, i do it in a view/storeproc/table function in sql and i simply call it.

Comment: Fredou, that's not an option. All queries need to be in LINQ.

Comment: Hamlet, I'll try it out tomorrow morning

Comment: Hamlet, I tried referring to aLeftJoin.ItemNumber instead of x.ItemNumber in the equals to b.ItemNumber, but it said it wasn't in the scope.  So I tried aLeft.ItemNumber and that worked, but has the problem I thought it would.  When I checked the SQL Profiler query, it refers to the results of "a" and I need these Left Joins to be independent of each other.